# How to generate PDF dynamically based on values from the database in WordPress

Tags: database, mysql, pdf

How to generate PDF by using the values from database without using plugin in WordPress.

For example, I have a form and will enter the Name. Then it needs to fetch the data from DB based on the entered Name and need to generate the PDF dynamically.

Comment: Not strictly speaking from the database, but I've used these tutorials to generate PDFs using custom fields from posts on my WordPress site before: [Tutorial 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-pdf-file-using-php/), [Tutorial 2](https://apitemplate.io/blog/how-to-generate-pdf-documents-using-php/), [Tutorial 3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-pdf-file-using-php/). You'd just need to fill in the missing step of retrieving data from the database.

Comment: note that you can ask how to do it, but you can't ask for recommendations of tutorials for it, asking for recommendations here is offtopic and you need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer, not the most useful link

Answer (score 1):

Using the FPDF library (found at http://www.fpdf.org) you generate PDFs on the fly using any data from your WP site.

```
function wpse60844_generate_pdf( $post ) {
    /* Define paths for where the PDF will be permanently or temporarily saved */
    define( 'FPDF_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . '/fpdf/' );
    define( 'SAVE_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'fpdf/pdfs/' );
    $pdf_dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'fpdf/pdfs/';
    
    /* If the directory doesn't already exist, generate it */
    if( !file_exists ( $pdf_dir ) ) :
        wp_mkdir_p( $pdf_dir );
    endif;
    
    /* Bring in the FPDF files so this all works */
    require( FPDF_PATH .'fpdf.php' );
    require( FPDF_PATH .'writeHTML.php' );
    
    /* Start retrieving your data from the WP DB, whether it's post_meta or some other data, no difference, just get your data into variables */
    $yourdata                       = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_key', true );
    $moredata                       = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_key', true );
    
    /* Now you begin to generate the HTML that will be converted to a PDF
     * Careful as some standard HTML won't work, like `<strong>` or `<em>`, use `<b>` or `<i>` */
    $html    = '<b>Some Label: ' . $yourdata . '</b><br><br>';
    $html   .= '<b>Some other Label: ' . $moredata . ' </b><br>';
    /* Keep going until you have all the content and layout you need */
    
    /* generating the PDF itself */
    $pdf = new hFPDF( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
    
    /* this is where the actual HTML you built above gets added as PDF. */
    $pdf->WriteHTML( utf8_decode( $html ) );
    $pdf->Output( SAVE_PATH . 'whatever-your-filename-is.pdf', 'F' );
    global $pdf_filename;
    $pdf_filename = SAVE_PATH . 'whatever-your-filename-is.pdf';

    /* Next you either have to write a function to mail this to your self using `wp_mail()`
    * Or send over the download path via AJAX and then download the PDF
    * To keep things clean you should also probably delet the PDF after it has been downloaded/sent
    * The rest is really up to you. */
}
add_action( 'the_action_that_triggers_pdf_send_or_download', 'wpse60844_generate_pdf' );
```

There's a lot of detail work involved and the odd character here or there can break the whole process. So be careful and I would honestly try to first output a single line PDF and then line by line add in the extra data, as that'll make it easier to help figure out where an error popped up.